# Does it seem odd to say "I'm in love WITH you?"

Tags: phrase-origin

I'm brand new to this site so please be kind. It has always struck me as odd to declare one's love for the very 1st time to another by saying, "I'm in love WITH you."  The brief definition I found for WITH was the Oxford one; accompanied by.  Which means both people would be in love with each other.  Why not just say "I love you?"  Does anyone know where the expression came from?

Comment: Do people actually say that ? Do they not rather state, in narrative, 'I am in love with X' meaning, as you say, that the the affection is mutual. But to the loved one, do they not state, as you say 'I love you.' [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+love+with+you%2CI+love+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20love%20with%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20love%20you%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: “I’m in love with you”  shortcuts the following conversation:  A: “I’m in love.” B: “Oh yeah? With who(m)?” A: “With you!”

Comment: Both expressions are open-ended.

Comment: Most people do say "I love you" first. "I'm in love with you" is a much stronger sentiment. I can't imagine someone starting with that...

Comment: Not as odd as 'I'm friends with him'.

Answer (score 5):

This is a matter of emphasis.

Consider the phrases you mention:

> I love you

You might love a variety of food, your dog, your cat, or a person of course.

To say *I love you* certainly conveys a strong affection, but it doesn't always have to carry the same degree of affection as :

> I'm in love with you

The word ***in*** creates a sense of being in the middle of this emotion, it's a much stronger sense of love, and idiomatically refers to love between one person and another. The use of the word *in* creates a stronger intensity of the sense of love.

You might think of other examples of the word in being used, e.g:

> I'm in trouble.
>
> I'm in danger.

Just as the word in operates in the above examples, a sense of almost being caught up is created, you are so *in* love, that this is something happening to you, almost as if you are powerless to choose otherwise, which creates a very strong sense of that feeling and emotion.

Which need not be the case when you simply actively *love* something or someone.

Comment: Either form can be said more emphatically than the other.

Comment: Verbally with tonal emphasis I do agree. Syntactically "I love you", can never be as strong as "I'm in love with you" however.

Comment: Ah, but love is never in the syntax. It’s in the semantics and attitudes surrounding the communication.

Comment: May I suggest that *in love* Idiomatically refers to *romantic* love. (Which may be what you were getting at, but you didn't use the word.)

Comment: 'Haps. But **where** on earth does the expression come from?

Comment: "I love you" is reflected in action, whereas, "I am in love with you" refers to the state/condition I am in. Doesn't the second sound more mature?

Comment: The OP is puzzled by the role of *with* in this phrase, not by the role of *in*.

Comment: It's not just a matter of emphasis, being "in love with" a person implies romantic love as opposed to familial love. If you say "I'm in love with Janet" and Janet is your sister, it will raise eyebrows.

Comment: @barbecue 'familial' in a very broad sense.  Imagine two young men stumbling out of a drinking establishment.  "I love you, man!" would not be unusual for friends to say but "I'm in love with you, man!" would be a wholly different kind of conversation.

Comment: @JimmyJames I had trouble coming up with the right word. Platonic didn't seem to cover it either.

Answer (score 5):

The OED has a good definition for *with* in this sense:

> After words expressing conduct or feeling towards (a person, etc.).
>   In some cases now replaced by other prepositions, e.g. *envious of*. In expressions of hostile action or feeling, this coincides with 2.

Compare the other expressions under this definition:

- have patience with
- be annoyed with
- be gentle with

Here’s an early example of *in love with*:

> He would talke..of the stories of the Scripture, so sweetely..as I was woonderfully in loue with him.

Foure Bks. Husbandry, 1577

Also notable is that Shakespeare used the expression in *Two Gentlemen of Verona*, 1616:

> I was in loue with my bed.

Answer (score 1):

"To be in love with" is a more specific version of "to love". "To be in love with" specifically means *romantic* love, "to love" does not.

You might love your dog or your child, but you wouldn't be *in* love with them.

Comment: this is incorrect. “[Much of Wall Street fell in love with Obama](http://blogs.reuters.com/chrystia-freeland/2012/11/09/obama-the-super-rich-and-the-election/)”  I don’t think this is romantic love, or at least I hope not.

Comment: @Laurel Actually, yes, that is what it means.  But they are using it figuratively instead of literally.

Comment: And people will speak figuratively of animals. "I went to the pound, and as soon as I saw that dog I fell in love with him."